# Android how to map multiple image to multiple imagebuttons programmatically?

Tags: android

I have 16 images namely ic_btn_exercise0 - ic_btn_exercise15

I want to map those images to 16 imageButton programmatically.

I have an idea create array of int to keep reference to images like this.

```
int[] drawableArray = {R.drawable.ic_btn_exercise0,...,R.drawable.ic_btn_exercise15};

for(int i=0;i<16;i++)
     imageButton[i].setBackgroundResource(drawableArray[i]);
```

But this way is a bit hard coding is there any better way to map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could generate the `drawable` `id` on the fly (runtime) as follows:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
    int current_id =  this.getResources().getIdentifier("ic_btn_exercise".concat(String.valueOf(i)), "drawable" ,getPackageName());
    imageButton[i].setBackgroundResource(current_id);
}
```

Similarly, you do not have to maintain an array of image buttons. You can get the id of the image button just like I mentioned above..

Comment: sorry what is getPackageName()?

Comment: Oh just context.getPackageName

Answer (score 0):

you could use the CustomAdapter like this

```
   import android.content.Context;
   import android.view.View;
   import android.view.ViewGroup;
   import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
   import android.widget.ImageButton;

   public class CutomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        Context mContext;
        int drawableArray[];

            public CutomAdapter(Context mContext, int[] drawableArray) {
    super();
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.drawableArray = drawableArray;
}
@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageButton temp = new ImageButton(mContext);
    temp.setImageResource(drawableArray[position]);
    temp.setId(position);
    return temp;
}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}
@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
 }
```